# simple question concerning NSString adding multiple strings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a fairly simple question concerning NSString however it doesn't seem to do what I want.

this is what i have

`NSString *title = [NSString stringWithformat: character.name, @"is the character"];`

This is a line in my parser takes the charactername and inserts in into a plist , however it doesn't insert the @"is the character"  is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong. It should be :

```
NSString *title 
    = [NSString stringWithformat:@"%@ is the character", character.name];
```

assuming that character.name is another `NSString`.

Read the Formatting [String Objects paragraph](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943) of the [String Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html) to learn everything about formatting strings.

Comment: Thanks however it doesn't seem to work
even if i do this , it just fails to add the second string.
NSString *title 
    = [NSString stringWithformat:@"%s is the character", @"%s is the character two"];

Comment: You need to use $@ if passing an NSString, or %s if passing a C string.

Answer (score 0):

`stringWithFormat` takes a format string as the first argument so, assuming `character.name` is the name of your character, you need:

```
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithformat: @"%s is the character",
    character.name];
```

What you have is the character name as the format string so, if it's `@"Bob"` then `Bob` is what you'll get.  If it was `"@Bob %s"`, that would work but would probably stuff up somewhere else that you display just the character name :-)

Note that you should use `"%s"` for a C string, I think `"%@"` is the correct format specifier if character.name is an NSString itself.

Comment: mmm thank you for your quick reply, however this doesn't seem to be the case. I tried it  but knew it would fail since I already tried 
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithformat:  @"is the character", character.name];   And then it seems to take the "is the character" perfectly.

Comment: That's because you don't have the "%s" in there (it should be @"%s is the character", not @"is the character"). When you put the "%s" into your format string, it will be replaced with the string contained in next argument (i.e., character.name). See also update if character.name is an NSString rather than a C string.

Comment: The code example should probably use %@ instead of %s. In my experience C strings are very rarely used in Cocoa, but %@ will work for any NSObject.